# Penetrating through Z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good evening everyone. I have a project that I am working on and I can't seem to find an answer or solve. I have the following idea and I was looking for a pure css solution. If it can't be done please let me know.

I have the following

```
div#1 {z-index: 1; }
div#2 {z-index: 2; }
div#3 {z-index: 3; }
```

div#1: has an image
div#2: has a bg color gradient overlay(top-bottom)
div#3: a circle (going to be a magnifying glass)

Is there a way to penetrate through div#2 within div#3 using pure css? I haven't found a css or jquery solution for dilemma. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle to check it out.

Comment: What does penetrate mean? You want a click to go trough div 2 and reach div 1?

Comment: @RaduDiță So I have a bg-image(z-index:1), bg-overlay(z-index:2), and a div(z-index:3). While the rest of the container is under z-index:2, I want z-index 3 to penetrate z-index:2 so its clear and not under an overlay. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following fiddle. Hope this is what you are looking for.

[Try this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmceLf0k/2/)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="image">
     <div class="overlay"> </div>
     <div class="search-lens">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/512/Very-Basic-Search-icon.png"
     </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not. It doesn't look like it will work. It looks like typical stack behavior with z-index. Let me clarify further. My structure is from bottom-to-top of stack. bg-image, bg-color-overlay, a div that penetrates through bg-color-overlay so the user can see the bg-image without the overlay. While the rest of the container is under the overlay.

Comment: I still don't see your background. What you have is the same of what i have.

Comment: you can give your image URL there and confirm.